# Using self-executing function with a closure as the listener in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, closures

I am using the following code to add an event listener on a DOM element:

```
var me = this;

element.addEventListener('click', function(element) {
    return function(evt) { 
        me.handler(evt, element); 
    };
} (element) , false);
```

When I click the element, the handler is called with the event and the element as parameters.

I have read through the information about closures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), but I'm still not clear how the event object gets associated with the evt variable.

Comment: There's a reasonable chance that the code will simplify to `element.addEventListener('click', this.handler, false);`. `evt` will be passed naturally to the handler, as the only parameter. Inside the handler, `this` will refer to the clicked element, so there's no need to pass it.

Comment: Regarding the code in the question, you won't find anything in the "closures" literature to explain `evt`. Only `element` is trapped in the closure. `evt` is the sole argument of a returned function, which becomes the click handler - as if you had attached the inner function directly, without the outer (closure-forming) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use

```
var me = this;
element.addEventListener('click', function(evt) { 
     me.handler(evt, element); 
} , false);
```

> I'm still not clear how the event object gets associated with the evt
>   variable.

If you use `addEventListener`, when the event is fired, the event listener receives an argument which is the event.

Then, when you add your event listener, the following code

```
function(element) {
    return function(evt) { 
        me.handler(evt, element); 
    };
} (element)
```

is evaluated and returns the following function

```
function(evt) { 
    me.handler(evt, element); 
}
```

which is the event handler. Then, its first argument `evt` is the event.

Comment: Maybe `element` is not a constant variable, for example in a loop.

Comment: @Bergi Then, instead of adding an event handler per iteration, it would be better to add a single event handler which does the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I ended up using `this.handler.bind(this, element)`